# Can't access methods of a java generics class

Tags: java, generics

I recently wrote some code that was *full* of code-duplication, and I wanted to improve it. I have sets of objects that are very similar, but not quite similar enough, as I'll explain below.

I'll start with the first set of objects. I have three objects,  `TagProbability`, `WordProbability`, and `TokenProbability`. These all have exactly the same methods, they have one data member of a different type. Two of them have a `String` and the other has an `enum` that I created, `SpeechTag`. I wanted to extract this into a single class, since most of their methods have basically the same implementation. I know that you can accomplish this type of thing using generics:

This is what I am using:

```
public class WordProbability extends ProbabilityPair<Str>
{
    public WordProbability(String tag)
    {
        super(tag);
    }
    ...
}
```

Where `ProbabilityPair` has the following structure.

```
public abstract class ProbabilityPair<T>
{
    public T key;
    private int count;
    private double probability;

    protected ProbabilityPair(T key)
    {
        this.key = key;
        count = 1;
        probability = 0d;
    }

    public void increment()
    {
        ++count;
    } 
    ...
}
```

This seems to be working. Each of these three classes extend from `ProbabilityPair` with their correct `key`. I am trying to take this a step further. I have three other objects that are essentially containers for different `ProbabilityPair`'s.

Here is an example of one of the containers:

```
public class Words
{
    public List<WordProbability> words;
    public int totalCount;

    public Words()
    {
        words = new ArrayList<>();
        totalCount = 0;
    }

    public void add(WordProbability word)
    {
        if (words.contains(word))
        {
            words.get(words.indexOf(word)).increment();
        } else
        {
            words.add(word);
        }
        ++totalCount;
    }
    ...
}
```

I tried to extract the `add` method into another generic class, `Container` as follows:

```
public class Container<ProbabilityPair>
{
    private List<ProbabilityPair> members;
    private int totalCount;

    public void add(ProbabilityPair member)
    {
        if (members.contains(member))
        {
            members.get(members.indexOf(member)).increment();
        } else
        {
            members.add(member);
        }
        ++totalCount;
    }
}
```

But the line `members.get(members.indexOf(member)).increment();` doesn't compile. It can't find the method. It is in ProbabilityPair, as you can see in the above snippet.

I think I am misunderstanding how generics would work in this instance, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT** Let me explain a little further. Each container functions more like a set than a list, really. It holds one of each `ProbilityPair`, and that pair holds it's count (and by association, probability). So, when I add, I check to see if it is there, and if it is, increment the count instead of adding a new object.

Comment: I don't understand. If you already have the `member` why are you trying to get it?

Comment: You should write `Container<P>` and then use `List<ProbabilityPair<P>>`, otherwise compiler doesn't know that type parameter `ProbabilityPair` has any other methods than methods provided by `Object`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I edited my question to explain my reasoning.

Comment: If you know it it's there, you don't need to `get` it again, you already have a reference to it in `member`. Or are these different instances?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The `member` passed in as a parameter doesn't necessarily refer to something in the list. So, I need to check if there is something in the list that matches my parameters (i.e. `.equals()`). If it is, increment the count of the one in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Container<ProbabilityPair>
```

Declares a type variable called `ProbabilityPair` which gets erased to `Object`.

`Object` does not have an `increment` method. So the call fails.

---

You should add a bound to your type variable, and change it's name to not clash with your `ProbabilityPair` type.

```
public class Container<T extends ProbabilityPair<?>> {
    private List<T> members;
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit of `Container<T extends ProbabilityPair<?>>` over just `Container<T>` with a `List<ProbabilityPair<T>`?

Comment: @CacheStaheli The container is for ```WordProbability```, so you would have variables of the type ```Container<WordProbability>```, whereas with ```Container<T>``` you would have variables like ```Container<String>``` to hold ```WordProbability``` and other types extending ```ProbabilityPair<String>```, which is not very readable.

Comment: Makes sense. I think it looks cleaner this way as well. It worked, by any means.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define `Container` correctly because you defined it to be a generic class whose generic parameter is named `ProbabilityPair` which has nothing to do with the generic class of the same name. It is exactly as defining `class Container<U>`.

I suppose you want to define `Container` as generic like this:

```
public class Container<U> {
    private List<ProbabilityPair<U>> members;
```

etc. A `Container` of something contains a `ProbabilityPair` on something. Right?